# Navigation Component - Problem with Livedata lifecycle

Tags: android, android-livedata

I'm beginning with navigation components and I'm facing some problem with a livedata observer.

For example: 
I have this livedata, who manage auth response from server.

```
viewModel.authenticate.observe(this, Observer {
        manageAuthResponse(it)
        })
```

Everything works fine, and I go to Fragment B.
But when I'm in Fragment B, and I try to go back to Fragment A (who contains that livedata), the `Observer` fires again with the previous result (SUCCESS).

How can I prevent this?

When I go back, I want to refresh this result and prevent livedata observer to be fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your LiveData object in a `ConsumableValue` like this

```
class ConsumableValue<T>(private val data: T) {

    private var consumed = false

    fun consume(block: ConsumableValue<T>.(T) -> Unit) {
        if (!consumed) {
            consumed = true
            block(data)
        }
    }
}
```

then in viewmodel

```
val authenticate = MutableLiveData<Consumable<AuthenticationObject>>()
```

and in your fragment

```
viewModel.authenticate.observe(this, Observer { consumable ->
        consumable.consume {
            manageAuthResponse(it)
        }
    })
```

Comment: But this is a bad implementation by me? Or its a kind of bug with navigation and livedata?

Comment: That's how LiveData works as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata): *"If a lifecycle becomes inactive, it receives the latest data upon becoming active again. For example, an activity that was in the background receives the latest data right after it returns to the foreground."*

Comment: Google does the same thing, they just call it "SingleEventLiveData" or somthing like that.

Comment: Actually if you look at the [conditional navigation docs around user login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#user_login), it specifically treats the LiveData as **state** and not events (which LiveData was never meant for).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hello Ian, I'm adapting "Multiple back stacks" in my BottomNav app. Turns out the state(like scroll postion) of RecyclerView, which is feeded with LiveData, can't be saved/restored as this feature expects. Is this an expected outcome? What should I do to have the RV state saved/restored after switching between bottom tabs? I don't want to give up LiveData for the RecyclerView. Thanks in advance. I had been expecting this Multiple back stacks feature for a long time: )

Comment: @gg - RecyclerView already [restores its scroll position](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Great thanks for your quick help. RecyclerView is well handled. Other possible component using livedata and not patched like RecycledView, will still have this problem. Am I right? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @gg - for every type of data, fragments have an API for [saving state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) that covers that case.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Please bear with me. what I expected is android itself takes care of restoring all the views' states in the fragment. Besides recyclerview you already explained, I found menu option in my toolbar still lost it's state.  Is it possible to achieve this without too much effort? Or do I have to take care of maybe more views one by one? I'm using BottomNavigationView and new Navigation components which supports multiple back stack. So I thought it could restore all views' state by default. I'm a J2EE programmer and know little kotlin. Thanks for your time teaching me.

Comment: @ianhanniballake just one quick question, if I have to handle the views' state by myself, what state of fragment does this multiple back stack feature save/restore? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the LiveDate Like this

```
open class LiveEvent<T> : MediatorLiveData<T>() {

  private val observers = ArraySet<ObserverWrapper<in T>>()

  @MainThread
  override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
    val wrapper = ObserverWrapper(observer)
    observers.add(wrapper)
    super.observe(owner, wrapper)
  }

  @MainThread
  override fun observeForever(observer: Observer<in T>) {
    val wrapper = ObserverWrapper(observer)
    observers.add(wrapper)
    super.observeForever(wrapper)
  }

  @MainThread
  override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<in T>) {
    if (observers.remove(observer)) {
      super.removeObserver(observer)
      return
    }
    val iterator = observers.iterator()
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      val wrapper = iterator.next()
      if (wrapper.observer == observer) {
        iterator.remove()
        super.removeObserver(wrapper)
        break
      }
    }
  }

  @MainThread
  override fun setValue(t: T?) {
    observers.forEach { it.newValue() }
    super.setValue(t)
  }

  private class ObserverWrapper<T>(val observer: Observer<T>) : Observer<T> {

    private var pending = false

    override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
      if (pending) {
        pending = false
        observer.onChanged(t)
      }
    }

    fun newValue() {
      pending = true
    }
  }
}
```

then in ViewModel

```
val viewModel = LiveEvent<Resource<String>>()
```

This solution is work for me

You can check out the code [in this github](https://github.com/hadilq/LiveEvent)